# Badge color doesn't change, in firefox, using crossrider API (setBadgeText)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, colors, badge, crossrider

I'm using crossrider, and I want to change the badge color of the browser button

Here's the code (in background.js)

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
    appAPI.browserAction.setBadgeText('0', [255, 127, 127, 125]); // GREY Color
});
```

The code works well in Chrome. But in Firefox, I cannot change the badge color to any color other than "red" ! It's always red despite any change in the array values in background code !

How to change its color ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the icon **first** using *[setResourceIcon](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setResourceIcon)* as stated in the docs? (For more information, see [appAPI.browserAction](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction))

I used the following code and it works as expected:

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
    // Make sure you have an image in the resources folder
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('images/icon.png');
    appAPI.browserAction.setBadgeText('Icon');
    appAPI.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor([0,0,255,100]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm asking about setBadgeText (not setBadgeBackgroundColor), It is supposed that setBadgeText may have another parameter for background color, check: http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setBadgeText .... if you try this api you will find that it cannot change the color !

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. First, please note that for the button to function correctly, you must first set the icon using setResourceIcon. Once set, the color can be set. Note: The issue you reported has been resolved and should work once you rebuild your extension (rebuild the extension by changing the description, saving the changes, and then reinstalling the extension). Apologies for the inconvenience.